# Pixelmon shut down. Can I still play?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-pixelmon

Recently, Nintendo/The Pokemon Company "asked" Pixelmon to shut down. Which they did.

Is it still possible to download and play Pixelmon on pc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official Pixelmon mod has been shut down. However, a quick google search revealed Pixelmon Reforged, found at https://www.reforged.gg, which can be downloaded through the Technic launcher:

DISCLAIMER: I do not provide any guarantees towards the lawfulness, quality, stability and/or security of the Pixelmon Reforged project. This is just what I found during a quick Google search. It might work, it might not, and it might also be taken down by Nintendo soon.